# given Data set, analyze to come up with possible out comes in excel

Tags: excel, statistics, data-analysis

I know this looks simply to you but for me this is heavy critical thinking. Help me to improve my question if not clear and i will edit the post question. The instruction is to illustrate what are the possible outcomes such as (charts, tables etc.) based on the given dataset. 3 things to understand
1. Total Booking request 
2. Total accepted booking
3. Total completed

the scenario in here is there is a company x who offers a service(Vehicles used for transporting goods) from one city to another.

The question is how am i going to illustrate useful reports based on the given dataset. In my own understanding i tried to come up first with the idea of statistical reports that illustrates how progressive is the company every single month, also their performances if they are failed or not with their monthly target deliveries *ex: target for january is to do 20 deliveries per day* and i already did this reports but the thing that i want to figure out is how am i going to illustrate using charts the *Note : Schedule Booking = a booking can be requested one day, but completed another day (ex. I booked a delivery for next Saturday)* `this note was shown below`

as i understand this note there are some scenario that the completed booking could be done also not just in a day but maybe could be done after a week. self-realization. Help me to figure this out, how am i going to solve the note.

this is my current output:
[image]
[image]

this the give dataset
[image]

and this is the instruction
[image]

Hi,please inform me with my flaws about my explanations that needed to rephrase the post. Thankyou i just need some advice.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what the problem is? What is the problem you are facing because of the note?

Comment: Specifically yes because of the note given in the picture.  It makes me confused because my answers are based on the completed deliveries made in a day but i dont know how to identify the note.